# Matrices, prove that if $XY=0$ and other conditions, then $\det(X+Y) =\det(X- Y) $

Tags: matrices, determinant

Prove that if $XY=0$ and $\det(X) =\det (Y) =0$, and both $\det(X+Y)$ and $\det(X-Y)$ are positive, then they are equal. I noticed it is enough to prove that $YX=0$.

Thanks

Edit: i mean prove that $\det(X+Y)=\det(X-Y)$

Comment: How can $\det(X-Y)>0$ and $X=Y$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe i mean the determinants are equal. Check the edit above. Sorry!

Comment: BTW: Some of the "other conditions" are not really needed: If you have $\det(X) \neq 0$, then $XY = 0$ implies $Y = 0$, and the claim becomes trivial. Likewise, if $\det(Y) \neq 0$, then $XY = 0$ implies $X = 0$, so that $\det(X+Y) = \det Y$ and $\det (X-Y) = \det(-Y) = (-1)^n \cdot \det(Y)$, so that the claim (if both are positive, they are equal) is also trivial. So what you really are asking is if $XY = 0$ and if $\det(X\pm Y) >0$, then $\det(X+Y) = \det(X-Y)$.

Comment: Maybe interesting for other answerers: The OP mentions that it would be enough to show $YX = 0$. While true that this would be sufficient, it is not true that this follows from the given assumptions. As a counterexample consider $
X = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
\quad
Y = \left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right).
$

Comment: Final comment @LiviuAntohi: Could you maybe explain where you encountered this problem, or what the context is? This might give some clue as to what techniques one should use for the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a contest problem and there might be some nice tricks behind it, but without knowing the tricks, the problem can still be solved in a straightforward manner.

By a change of basis, we may assume that $X$ is already in rational canonical form. Then $X$ cannot contain a non-trivial nilpotent diagonal sub-block, otherwise, if the first diagonal sub-block of $X$ is
$$
\pmatrix{\mathbf 0^T&0\\ I_k&\mathbf0},
$$
then the condition $XY=0$ would force the first $k$ rows of $Y$ to be zero, but then both the first rows of $X$ and $Y$ would be zero, contradicting the assumption that $X\pm Y$ is non-singular.

Therefore, by another change of basis, we may assume that $X=D\oplus0_{r\times r}$ for some non-singular matrix $D$. Now the condition $XY=0$ means that $Y=\pmatrix{0_{(n-r)\times(n-r)}&0\\ \ast &Z}$ for some $r\times r$ matrix $Z$. Hence $\det(X+Y)=\det(D)\det(Z)$, $\det(X-Y)=(-1)^r\det(D)\det(Z)$ and the rest is trivial.